# C++ code that cannot access private members of a class using derived class

Tags: c++

I've currently got code below in which i am trying to initialize the data members x, y and z to 0 when an object of type Solid is being instantiated. The lines 25, 26 and 27 contain errors, how would I rewrite these lines to access the x and y members and set them to 0?

edit 1: I've written out my code below.

edit 2: To clear things up, the only lines of code that can be altered are the lines that contain errors. The derived class should be rewritten to access the private data members.

```
class Shape
{

private:

    int x, y;

protected:

    string _type;

public:

    Shape() { x = y = 0; }
    Shape(int a, int b) { x = a; y = b; }
    string type() { return _type; }
    void stype(string val) { _type + val; }
    int getx() { return x; }
    int gety() { return y; }

};

class Solid : public Shape
{

    int z;

public:

    Solid() { x = y = z = 0; } // errors
    Solid(int a, int b, int c) { x = a; y = b; z = c; } //
    int Volume() { return x * y * z; } //
};

int main()

{

    Solid ob1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post code as text, not as a link to an image.

Comment: You should post your code here. Not an image of the code.

Comment: A derived class doesn't inherit access to private data members. However, it does inherit a full parent object, which contains any private members which that class declares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access private members of a base class, and the point of this exercise is that you don't need to - not that you should come up with a way of doing it.

Your default constructor should only set its own member - `Shape`s default constructor takes care of its own members:

```
Solid() { z = 0; }
```

or (the preferred method, which actually is initialisation and not an assignment)

```
Solid() :z(0) {}
```

The other constructor should initialise the base, and then `z`:

```
Solid(int a, int b, int c) : Shape(a,b), z(c){}
```

and `Volume` should use the provided accessors:

```
int Volume() { return getx() * gety() * z; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inherited class can not access to parent's private attributes. It can access his protected attributes, so you can move your variables to protected. Another option is to use setter function (like getX) and use them.

edit: change only for the relevant errors lines:

```cpp
Solid():Shape(0,0) { this->z = 0; } 
Solid(int a, int b, int c):Shape(a,b) { this->z = c; }
int Volume() { return this->getx() * this->get.y * this->z; }
```

when you create `Solid` object, you can also call for the c'tor of `Shape` with the values you want. That is the right way to initialize values of `x, y` when creating new inherited objects. For the third line calculation you should use `getx()` and `gety()` functions. 
As said before, the key is to understand that x and y are not directly accessible for Solid object

Comment: I cant do this, it's part of a question. I am supposed to be altering those lines which contain errors to access the variables instead. I somehow have to use the getx and gety functions to do this.

Comment: @ronny45098 I edited my post to alter only the three relevant lines

Comment: please accept one the answers people gave you, to make clear that your question has been answered

Answer (score 0):

**You can't, directly, inherit the private members of the parent class.** You could use its constructor in your derived class(child class) constructor though-its cool, but I don't use that way. Some information about the access specifiers(the type of inheritance you declare):

- **Public:**  Your derived class inherits the protected members of your parent class as protected and the public as public.
- **Protected:** Your derived class inherits the protected members of your parent class as protected and the public as protected.
- **Private:**  Your derived class inherits the protected members of your parent class as private and the public as private.

Notice again that the private members of your parent class are not inherited. This should do the trick:
Change:

```
private:
    int x, y;
```

Into:

```
protected:
    int x, y;
```

Using the parent class constructor should look like:

```
class Solid : public Shape
{
private://doesn't matter, just for the aesthetics
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;

public:

    Solid() { 
    Shape();
    z = 0; } // errors
```

And the direct way is(your code with added x,y as properties of the class):

```
class Solid : public Shape
    {
    private://doesn't matter, just for the aesthetics
        int x;
        int y;
        int z;

    public:

        Solid() {x=y=z = 0; } // errors
```

Comment: Just to clarify, don't do all the changes, just 1 of them. These are 3 different ways to tackle the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Private data members are never inherited in any type of inheritance. Hence the name private, but interestingly you can use friend class concept here and even private data members are inherited now,

please try to run the following code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class Shape
{

private:

    int x, y;

protected:

    string _type;

public:

    Shape() { x = y = 0; }
    Shape(int a, int b) { x = a; y = b; }
    string type() { return _type; }
    void stype(string val) { _type + val; }
    int getx() { return x; }
    int gety() { return y; }
    friend class Solid;

};

class Solid : public Shape
{

    int z;

public:

    Solid() { x = y = z = 0; } // errors
    Solid(int a, int b, int c) { x = a; y = b; z = c; } //
    int Volume() { return x * y * z; } //
};

int main()

{

    Solid ob1;

    return 0;
}
```

Now you can access x, y in inherited class also, since you declared class solid as friend of shape class.

Hope this answers your question.